# Build xib Interface Builder and load them as subview in iphone

Tags: interface, uiview, xib, builder, addsubview

what I would like to know if it's possible to build a view and its correspondent xib file.
Then, in a generic controller, load this view programmatically and add as a subview to the current view.

This subview should act as a generic info box which can be loaded by many controller.

thanks
Leonardo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution myself, after looking at some stackoverflow thread. So I would like to share what I found and see if it's an acceptable solution.
Basically this is what I did:

1. create a `MyView.m` view file with all my required IBOutlet
2. build a `MyView.xib` view in interface builder, leaving default file's owner and set view as `MyView.m`
3. use this piece of code

   ```
     NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
     MyView * myView = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
     [self addSubview:myView];
   ```

It works, actually...